# onClick, view not responding

Tags: java, android, xml, view, onclick

Im trying to use a onclick method. My class has..

```
Public class Homework extends Activity implements View.OnClickListner
```

And I have a method like this:

```
@Override
Public void onClick(View v){
Log.I(TAG, "Click");
}
```

But when I click on the view (which has click=true ) in the xml it doesn't come up with anything.

When the view is pressed it is meant to log "click" using a normal click listener it work tho but I dont want to use heaps of listeners.

Comment: You need to run `setOnClickListener(this)` for the button you want to act upon clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heve you **set the onClickListener** to that view?

You have to write this snippet in your code

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.your view id);
view.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML layout, attached to your button:

```
<Button ...
android:onClick="doClick" <!-- name is arbitrary, but must match activity method name -->
</Button>
```

Back in your activity:

```
...
public void doClick(View v){
    // actions for click response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: I hope it will work

```
    Public class Homework extends Activity implements View.OnClickListner {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  // replace main with your layout
        findViewById(R.id.view).setOnClickListener(this); // replace view with your id

    }

     }
@Override
Public void onClick(View v){
Log.I(TAG, "Click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should turn to use the simplest way that I always do as below:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            button3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
                 switch(v.getId()){
                     case R.id.button1:
                          //DO something
                     break;
                     case R.id.button2:
                          //DO something
                     break;
                     case R.id.button3:
                          //DO something
                     break;
                 }

        }
    };
```